# GET max record action with action_type for each post by category ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a POST table, a CATEGORY table, a ACTION table and ACTION_TYPE table, I explain the ACTION table contains all the actions that were made, and the table ACTION_TYPE contains the actions details for example the ACTION whose ID = 4 has ACTION_TYPE_ID = 1 for POST_ID 6, which mean an action was made for post number 50, we can have many actions for one post_id

The POST table

```
 id         title       content     category_id
----------  ----------  ----------  ------------  
 1          title1      Text...     3
 2          title2      Text...     1
 3          title3      Text...     1
 4          title4      Text...     3
 5          title5      Text...     2
 6          title6      Text...     1
```

The CATEGORY table

```
 id         name      
----------  ----------  
 1          category_1      
 2          category_2
 3          category_3
```

The ACTION_TYPE table

```
 id         name      
----------  ----------  
 1          updated
 2          deleted
 3          restored
 4          hided
```

The ACTION table

```
id         post_id         action_type_id    date
----------  ----------      --------------    -----
 1          1               1                 2017-01-01
 2          1               1                 2017-02-15
 3          1               3                 2018-06-10
 4          6               1                 2019-08-01
 5          5               2                 2019-12-09
 6          2               3                 2020-04-27
 7          2               1                 2020-07-29
 8          3               2                 2021-03-13
```

I explain the case, I have a query that it should normally count the actions performed on post for each ACTION_TYPE by category
for example the last ACTION with  ACTION_TYPE_ID 1 which is "update" of post number 1 with the category 3 and which was acording data at 2017-02-15

here is my query that bring the whole ACTIONS

```
select categories, actions,  count(*) as cnt_actions_per_cat
   from(
        select   
        case
        when ac.action_type_id is not null then act.name
        end as actions,
        case
        when p.category_id is not null then c.name
        else 'na'
        end as categories
        from action ac
        left join post p on ac.post_id = p.id  
        left join category c on p.category _id = c.id
        left join action_type act on ac.action_type_id = act.id
        where act.name in ('restored','deleted','updated')
        )
   group by categories, actions
;
```

here the result i get

```
categories   actions     cnt
-----------  ----------  -----------   
category_1   updated     2
category_1   deleted     1
category_1   restored    1
category_2   updated     0
category_2   deleted     1
category_2   restored    0
category_3   updated     2
category_3   deleted     0
category_3   restored    1
```

so to get the max actions performed on post for each ACTION_TYPE by category i added this line to my query " distinct  ac.post_id  AS action_post_id, max(ac.date) over (partition by  ac.post_id) as max_date, "

```
select categories, actions,  count(*) as cnt_actions_per_cat
   from(
        -- here is my line 
        select distinct  ac.post_id  AS action_post_id, max(ac.date) over (partition by  ac.post_id) as max_date,  
        case
        when ac.action_type_id is not null then act.name
        end as actions,
        case
        when p.category_id is not null then c.name
        else 'na'
        end as categories
        from action ac
        left join post p on ac.post_id = p.id  
        left join category c on p.category _id = c.id
        left join action_type act on ac.action_type_id = act.id
        where act.name in ('restored','deleted','updated')
        )
   group by categories, actions
;
```

but the problem is that i still don't get the right result so i would like to have result as follow : Here the result expected to be

```
categories   actions     cnt
-----------  ----------  -----------   
category_1   updated     2
category_1   deleted     1
category_1   restored    1
category_2   updated     0
category_2   deleted     1
category_2   restored    0
category_3   updated     1 -- 2017-02-15 because it should get the last (max) action with this action_type for this post  
category_3   deleted     0
category_3   restored    1
```

Best regards

Comment: In your expected results, why does the combination of `category_3|updated` have to show as a count of 1, but the combination of `category_1|updated` show a count of 2? There are 2 different dates for `category_1|updated`

Comment: Thank you @EJ Egyed i appreciate your support so yes there are 2 different dates for category_1|updated because each action belongs to two different posts

Answer (score 0):

This is a data densification problem that can be solved by using a partition outer join. The partition outer join repeatedly joins the relevant rows from the ACTION_TYPE type to each category, and the NVL turns the extra columns into zeroes.

```
select counts.categories, action_type.name actions, nvl(cnt_actions_per_cat, 0) cnt_actions_per_cat
from action_type
left outer join
(
   select categories, actions,  count(*) as cnt_actions_per_cat
      from(
         -- here is my line 
         select distinct  ac.post_id  AS action_post_id, max(ac.the_date) over (partition by  ac.post_id) as max_date,  
         case
         when ac.action_type_id is not null then act.name
         end as actions,
         case
         when p.category_id is not null then c.name
         else 'na'
         end as categories
         from action ac
         left join post p on ac.post_id = p.id  
         left join category c on p.category_id = c.id
         left join action_type act on ac.action_type_id = act.id
         where act.name in ('restored','deleted','updated')
         )
      group by categories, actions
) counts
    partition by (counts.categories)
    on (counts.actions = action_type.name)
where action_type.name in ('restored','deleted','updated')
order by categories, actions;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7xU8Sl4y) is a db<>fiddle that creates the schema and runs the query. (I made a few small modifications, such as changing the column "DATE" to "THE_DATE". And there's probably a way to clean this query up and remove multiple joins to ACTION_TYPE.)